# Rails uppercase/lowercase object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a fairly basic Ruby/Rails question but I'm not sure why it makes a difference if you call a class of an object in some circumstances vs calling an instance of that object in different places of the framework.

Say you have a model e.g. `Product` and you call `Product.new` you have a new instance of the class. But if you have certain methods that are defined in the model I only seem to be able to access these if I call the Class rather than an instance e.g. `Product.where(param, param)`. But I cannot call `product.where(param, param)` - why is this?

Comment: There is a decent right up on the difference between class methods and instance methods here. http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: Thanks that's quite a good article, I realised I have some methods from a gem which are not in the model which must be Class methods rather than instance methods. This must be why the behaviour is unexpected. Thanks again.

Comment: This is the problem with rails tutorials: they teach you nothing about ruby, and therefore all you know how to do is copy code.  No one can program rails without knowing ruby.  If you don't learn ruby, all you'll ever be able to do is copy code.  If you learn ruby, then try to think about how rails does stuff as you learn rails, and then try to duplicate what rails does in examples, you will actually learn something.

Comment: Actually, although I am not that experienced I did learn Ruby before Rails and don't just 'copy code'. I was aware of the general difference between calling the different methods - my problem was understanding what Rails is doing behind the scenes in certain situations. If you look at that guide that was referenced above even the author acknowledges that using example 2 (which is used throughout Rails) can make it quite confusing to know which is a class method and which is an instant method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of methods: Class methods, and instance methods. You must call the appropriate method on the right object.

```
class Product
  def self.foo
    # class method, only callable on Product
  end

  def name
    # instance method, callable on an instance of Product.
  end
end
```

If you attempt to call an instance method on a class, or vice versa, you'll see an undefined method error.

To use someone else's analogy, imagine a house and a blue print; the class is a blue print for an object, while a house would represent the instance. An instance of that class will have its own set of attributes (wall colour, window type, etc...).

Comment: I think the OP has acknowledged this. The OP just doesn't know why you would have one versus the other.

Comment: Actually, in Ruby there is only one type of method: instance method. The *relevant* question is: what class is the method defined in?

Answer (score 0):

What would this mean?

```
p = Product.find(1)
p.where('something == 2')
```

That doesn't make any sense, you have an instance, what are you querying for?  Good API design results in methods defined where they make sense.